# APPIUM (Android) - Not able to find the Login elements

Tags: appium, appium-android

Probably microsoft has updated the login screen for mobile view.
Not able to find the elements on LOGIN screen.

Attached is the screenshot, where I am trying to search for field to enter the email ID, but the last line selects the complete screen.[image]

Comment: Have you checked the last widget control_container? It might be that the View itself has some components which cannot be queried by Appium.

Comment: @PureVodka, the last widget control_container is for the top section in the screen, where it is written, "Sign in to your Microsoft account".

For this screen, the last xpath I am getting is:
'''
/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.webkit.WebView
'''
which selects the complete section, but I want the xpath/id of the field element

Comment: So thats it, the elements you are looking for are inside the WebView. From looking around you would need to set the WebView to debugable or you could find the url its send you to and through your browser check the ids and XPaths. Once you have the ID you can follow these Appium instructions for automating hybrid apps: http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/